# signInName exist in JWT, but I can't signin with that

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I created the claim signInName.username, put there in TP Write and Read, SignUp journey using logon email, but no success, I can't login yet.

Comment: What are you trying to acomplish?

Comment: I'm trying login with another username that else e-mail

Comment: Have you taken a look to [A B2C IEF Custom Policy which uses Usernames as the sign in identifier](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin#a-b2c-ief-custom-policy-which-uses-usernames-as-the-sign-in-identifier)?

Comment: I've reached the goal. It was ProxyIdentity without access to IEF.

Comment: Did you solved your issue? If so please post an answer so that others in the community can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Always check that the signature and encryption keys are correct.

Read link below

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started